# Data structure insert,delete,mode

Tags: data-structures

Here is the interview problem: Designing a data structure for a range of integers {1,...,M} (numbers can be repeated) support insert(x), delete(x) and return mode which return the most frequently number.

The interviewer said that we can do in O(1) for all the operation with preprocessed in O(M). He also accepted that I can do insert(x) and delete(x) in O(log(n)), return mode in O(1) with preprocessed in O(M).

But I can only give in O(n) for insert(x) and delete(x) and return mode in O(1), actually how can I give O(log (n)) or/and O(1) in insert(x) and delete(x), and  return mode in O(1) with preprocessed in O(M)?

Comment: if your algorithm takes O(n) for insert and delete then you should use divide and conquer approach to get to O(logn). Now think of a data structure which takes O(logn) for inserts and deletes. This should be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hear `O(log X)` operations, the first structures that comes to mind should be a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) and a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). For reference: (since I'm focussing on a heap below)

> A heap is a specialized tree-based data structure that satisfies the heap property: If A is a parent node of B then the key of node A is ordered with respect to the key of node B with the same ordering applying across the heap. ... The keys of parent nodes are always greater than or equal to those of the children and the highest key is in the root node (this kind of heap is called max heap) ....

A binary search tree doesn't allow construction (from unsorted data) in `O(M)`, so let's see if we can make a heap work (you can create a heap in `O(M)`).

Clearly we want the most frequent number at the top, so this heap needs to use frequency as its ordering.

But this brings us to a problem - `insert(x)` and `delete(x)` will both require that we look through the entire heap to find the correct element.

Now you should be thinking "what if we had some sort of mapping from index to position in the tree?", and this is exactly what we're going to have. If all / most of the `M` elements exist, we could simply have an array, with each index `i`'s element being a pointer to the node in the heap. If implemented correctly, this will allow us to look up the heap node in `O(1)`, which we could then modify appropriately, and move, taking `O(log M)` for both `insert` and `delete`.

If only a few of the `M` elements exist, replacing the array with a (hash-)map (of integer to heap node) might be a good idea.

Returning the mode will take `O(1)`.

---

`O(1)` for all operations is certainly quite a bit more difficult.

The following structure comes to mind:

```
3     2
^     ^
|     |         
5     7     4     1

12    14    15    18
```

To explain what's going on here - `12`, `14`, `15` and `18` correspond to the frequency, and the numbers above correspond to the elements with said frequency, so both `5` and `3` would have a frequency of `12`, `7` and `2` would have a frequency of `14`, etc.

This could be implemented as a double linked-list:

```
          /-------\                     /-------\
(12) <-> 5 <-> 3 <-> (13) <-> (14) <-> 7 <-> 2 <-> (15) <-> 4 <-> (16) <-> (18) <-> 1
  ^------------------/ ^------/ ^------------------/ ^------------/ ^------/
```

You may notice that:

I filled in the missing `13` and `16` - these are necessary, otherwise we'll have to update all elements with the same frequency when doing an `insert` (in this example, you would've needed to update `5` to point to `13` when doing `insert(3)`, because `13` wouldn't have existed yet, so it would've been pointing to `14`).

I skipped `17` - this is just be an optimization in terms of space usage - this makes this structure take `O(M)` space, as opposed to `O(M + MaxFrequency)`. The exact conditions for skipping a number is simply that it doesn't have any elements at its frequency, or one less than its frequency.

There's some strange things going on above the linked-list. These simply mean that `5` points to `13` as well, and `7` points to `15` as well, i.e. each element also keeps a pointer to the next frequency.

There's some strange things going on below the linked-list. These simply mean that each frequency keeps a pointer to the frequency before it (this is more space efficient than each element keeping a pointer to both it's own and the next frequency).

Similarly to the above solution, we'd keep a mapping (array or map) of integer to node in this structure.

To do an insert:

- Look up the node via the mapping.
- Remove the node.
- Get the pointer to the next frequency, insert it after that node.
- Set the next frequency pointer using the element after the insert position (either it is the next frequency, in which case we can just make the pointer point to that, otherwise we can make this next frequency pointer point to the same element as that element's next frequency pointer).

To do a remove:

- Look up the node via the mapping.
- Remove the node.
- Get the pointer to the current frequency via the next frequency, insert it before that node.
- Set the next frequency pointer to that node.

To get the mode:

Return the last node.

Answer (score 0):

Since range is fixed, for simplicity lets take an example M=7 (range is 1 to 7). So we need atmost 3 bit to represent each number.

0 - 000
1 - 001
2 - 010
3 - 011
4 - 100
5 - 101
6 - 110
7 - 111

Now create a b-tree with each node having 2-child (like Huffmann coding algo). Each leaf will contain the frequency of each number (initially it would be 0 for all). And address of these nodes will be saved in an array, with key as index (i.e. address for Node 1 will be at index 1 in array).

With pre-processing, we can execute insert, remove in O(1), mode in O(M) time.

1. insert(x) - go to location k in array, get address of node and increment counter for that node.
2. delete(x) - as above, just decrement counter if>0.
3. mode - linear search in array for maximum frequency (value of counter).